# Can I use the not operator in C++ on int values?

Tags: c++, int, logical-operators, negation

Strange question, but someone showed me this,
I was wondering can you use the not ! operator for int in C++? (its strange to me).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a=5, b=4, c=4, d;
   d = !( a > b && b <= c) || a > c && !b;
   cout << d;
   system ("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is cryptic code, not easy to read, with meaningless name for variables. `d = !( a > b && b <= c) || a > c && !b;` Please, program cleanly: Choose good names, and dont multiply numerous operation in one single line.

Comment: @Stephane: "someone showed me this". If the questioner didn't write the code, how to carry out your instructions? As it happens, only the `!b` is relevant to the question, so the rest could be dropped, but since the questioner doesn't understand the `!` operator, this might not be obvious.

Comment: @Steve. Okay, but I have come across those variable names so often...

Comment: @Stephane: in real code that might be a problem. In a question about syntax I certainly prefer `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` over names that relate to some specific programming task, and that might take effort to ignore.

Comment: @Steve, yep you are right... but there was also this !( a > b && b <= c) || a > c && !b; cryptic thing... It's not really about syntax, it's about uglyness ;-)  But yes you are right for syntax only topic, abc do re mi maybe can do it

Comment: @Stephane: I certainly agree that code is ugly, and I was quite glad the question wasn't, "please explain the whole of this horrible expression" :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes. For integral types, `!` returns `true` if the operand is zero, and `false` otherwise.

So `!b` here just means `b == 0`.

---

This is a particular case where a value is converted to a `bool`. The `!b` can be viewed as `!((bool)b)` so the question is what is the "truthness" of `b`. In C++, arithmetic types, pointer types and enum can be converted to `bool`. When the value is 0 or null, the result is `false`, otherwise it is `true` (C++ §4.1.2).

Of course custom classes can even overload the `operator!` or `operator`<*types can be convert to bool*> to allow the `!b` for their classes. For instance, `std::stream` has overloaded the `operator!` and `operator void*` for checking the failbit, so that idioms like

```
while (std::cin >> x) {   // <-- conversion to bool needed here
  ...
```

can be used.

(But your code `!( a > b && b <= c) || a > c && !b` is just cryptic.)

Answer (score 7):

Originally, in C (on which C++ is based) there was no Boolean type. Instead, the value "true" was assigned to any non-zero value and the value "false" was assigned to anything which evaluates to zero. This behavior still exists in C++. So for an `int x`, the expressions `!x` means "`x` not true", which is "`x` not non-zero", i.e. it's true if `x` is zero.

Comment: Sorry, I know I'm 8 years late, but do you have a quote from a C++ standard to back up your answer?

Answer (score 5):

You can, `!b` is equivalent to `(b == 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

The test for int is true for non-zero values and false for zero values, so not is just true for zero values and false for non-zero values.

Answer (score 3):

The build-in `!` operator converts its argument to `bool`. The standard specifies that ***there exists a conversion from any arithmetic type(`int`, `char`,.... `float`, `double`...) to bool***. If the source value is 0 the result is `true`, otherwise it is `false`