# C++ operator equal to C#

Tags: c#, c++

This code is C++. I can't convert it to C#.

The main problem is `!(value & 0xf)`. I don't know what it does!!

I don't know what operator `!(int)` does in C++

```
int GetBitPosition(uint8_t value)
{
    const int i4 = !(value & 0xf) << 2;
    value >>= i4;

    const int i2 = !(value & 0x3) << 1;
    value >>= i2;

    const int i1 = !(value & 0x1);

    const int i0 = (value >> i1) & 1 ? 0 : -8;

    return i4 + i2 + i1 + i0;
}
```

Comment: `!` in C / C++ is the logical `not` operator - i.e. it converts `true` to `false` and vice versa.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical

Comment: 0 is false, every other value is true.  Logical not then reverses that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!` is the [`not` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) in C++. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123568/10957435):

> Yes. For integral types, ! returns true if the operand is zero, and false otherwise.
>
> So !b here just means b == 0.

In other words, if C# doesn't have an equivalent operator (which I don't understand why it wouldn't), you can, in theory, use the C# equivalent of the following instead:

```
((value & 0xf) == 0) // parenthesis for readabillity
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int GetBitPosition(int value)
{
    int i4 = ((value & 0xf) == 0 ? 1 : 0) << 2;
    value >>= i4;

    int i2 = ((value & 0x3) == 0 ? 1 : 0)  << 1;
    value >>= i2;

    int i1 = (value & 0x1) == 0 ? 1 : 0 ;

    int i0 = ((value >> i1) & 1 ) == 1 ? 0 : -8;

    return i4 + i2 + i1 + i0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Answers are better if you add an explanation, not just code.

Comment: OP just wanted to know what `!` does not so much converting his code which is fine too.  Considering the OP’s attitude though I’m not sure I would have

Comment: Thank your for post the new code <3. and as `Chipster` some comments will be good for new ppl. but again ty <3

Comment: One should think about branching a bit. You have four conditions in this function. Would it be possible to replace all of them with simple boolean logic?